# Restricting typing at a distance from the end on an input field

Tags: html, css

I have an input field, at the end of which i've created a character counter: 
[image]

The problem is that now, it is possible to type beneath the counter which is no good:[image]
I would like the typing area to be restricted a certain distance before the end of the input field, something like this: [image]

I am aware of `maxlenght` but since the letters have different lengths i.e. you  can fit 183 "i" but only 57 "W", which would make for a really unintuitive typing experience, if your typing is cut off at the middle of the field.

Comment: Could you get away with just shortening the input, positioning the counter next to the input, and putting the border and background on a parent wrapper?

Comment: That would be quite messy, as always, I am trying to keep things as clean as possible, so I just thought there might be a solution that I just hadn't heard about

Comment: Well, there is. But it's also really messy. WIth a hidden span (not `display: none`!) with the same font family, font weight and font size - copy the contents of the div to the span and measure the length in pixels. Then compare to the pixel length of the input. If difference is too small then return false in an event handler for `keydown` on the input (making sure the key isn't delete/backspace)

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I am actually already using a span to display the typed text (that's how I got the color), so what you suggested might not be that far fetched

Comment: Comparing dynamic sizes is messy, what first @Scoots suggested is good. It's the common approach to this and almost on every page if you see a delete button nested in an input visually, it's achieved that way. Your case is the same but with a span. Stick to that.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the input, I will keep that in mind

Comment: Hey @Scoots if you want to put that in an answer, I will accept it

Comment: A'ight, writing it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two possible solutions that occur to me.

1.

Simply shortening the input and positioning the counter next to the input, then styling a common parent element to look like the input. This is the more simple and less error prone solution.

2.

This way is a bit more complicated, but basically what you would do is create a hidden element somewhere (**NB** not `display: none;`) with the same font size/weight/family and attach a `keydown` event handler to the input field.

In this handler you copy the contents on the input to the hidden element, measure the width in pixels and compare that to your input. If the difference is too small, you return false in your input handler, making sure you're not preventing the user from pressing delete or backspace first.

It should be noted however that this method is pretty difficult to get right and I would consider it to be the "dirty" solution.